# Cannot pitch canvas layer correctly in Mapbox GL JS

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I am moving some code from Leaflet into Mapbox GL JS. I have a 2d animated canvas which is rendered correctly when viewed top-down (pitch 0), rotated (bearing whatever), but is skewed when the pitch isn't zero. I have spent the past few days trying to correct it without much success.

My code needs to be able to convert between screen dimensions and map coordinates. E.g. for a given pixel, what lat-lon results (with `map.project([lon, lat])` ). Or for a lat-lon, what pixel does it correspond to (with `map.unproject([x,y])` ). When the canvas is rendered with pitch 0, the latitudes are equally spaced (*enough) across the pixels and everything works as desired. The conversions occur correctly.

When pitch is > 0, the coordinate conversions appear to work as expected as well. However, *I think* Mapbox GL JS takes the canvas, and turns it into a WebGL texture. This texture is then somehow scaled/rotated which turns the previous rectangle canvas into a trapezoid.

I need to be able to include this trapezoid scaling or account for this distortion in the canvas calculations.

**Rough Sample**

The snippet below is an attempt at replicating what is going on with a far simpler codebase. It's based on https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/canvas-source/. You'll see the circles moving around, turning into ovals at different points and stretching--they should remain circles. This is partly caused by the `map.unproject()` calls using the screen dimensions, which are used to determine the map bounds. In 2d space, this works well because the screen bounds are identical to the camera view. But *I think* in 3d space, the screen dimensions are distorted by the camera view, and so the relation is lost between screen--camera--map which causes the skew.

My goal is to either correct the skew, or somehow use the camera properties to create the bounds (and project/unproject), OR there's another way to solve this. Essentially I want what is on the canvas at particular coordinates to stay there and not moved when pitched.

Thank you!

```js
const PITCH = 45; // Change to 0 to see uniform shapes

// Based on https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/canvas-source/
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiYnVzaGZpcmVpbyIsImEiOiJjazU3NGwzNGEwM2QxM2VwcWJ0djk1amFyIn0.DP3giqn33iswMWzlclr9jg';


var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    zoom: 5,
    minZoom: 4,
    center: [95.899147, 18.088694],
    pitch: PITCH,
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11'
});



//Animation from https://javascript.tutorials24x7.com/blog/how-to-draw-animated-circles-in-html5-canvas

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasID');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var circles = [];
var radius = 20;

function Circle(x, y, dx, dy, radius, color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.dx = dx;
    this.dy = dy;

    this.radius = radius;

    this.draw = function () {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        ctx.strokeStyle = color;
        ctx.stroke();
    };

    this.update = function () {
        if (this.x + this.radius > 400 || this.x - this.radius < 0) {
            this.dx = -this.dx;
        }

        if (this.y + this.radius > 400 || this.y - this.radius < 0) {
            this.dy = -this.dy;
        }

        this.x += this.dx;
        this.y += this.dy;

        this.draw();
    };
}

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var color =
        '#' +
        (0x1000000 + Math.random() * 0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1, 6);
    var x = Math.random() * (400 - radius * 2) + radius;
    var y = Math.random() * (400 - radius * 2) + radius;

    var dx = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 2;
    var dy = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 2;

    circles.push(new Circle(x, y, dx, dy, radius, color));
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);

    for (var r = 0; r < 5; r++) {
        circles[r].update();
    }
}

animate();


let size = this.map.getContainer();
const nw = map.unproject([0, 0]);
const ne = map.unproject([size.clientWidth, 0]);
const se = map.unproject([size.clientWidth, size.clientHeight]);
const sw = map.unproject([0, size.clientHeight]);


map.on('load', function () {
    map.addSource('canvas-source', {
        type: 'canvas',
        canvas: 'canvasID',
        coordinates: [
            [nw.lng, nw.lat],
            [ne.lng, ne.lat],
            [se.lng, se.lat],
            [sw.lng, sw.lat],
        ],
        animate: true
    });

    map.addLayer({
        id: 'canvas-layer',
        type: 'raster',
        source: 'canvas-source'
    });
});
```

```css
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#map { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Canvas Demo</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.3.1/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.3.1/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvasID" width="400" height="400">Canvas not supported</canvas>
<div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```